Intuition of path-connectedness
I was studying topology when a question came to my mind.
I was considering the definition of path-connectedness. My basic question is the following: what makes the real interval $I=[0,1]$ (with topology induced by the Euclidean one) so special? Is it the fact that the frontier (seen in $\mathbb{R}$) has two points, therefore continuous functions from it are thought to "link" the two images?
Maybe a characterisation of its topology may be helpful, or recalling some of its properties that cannot be deduced by its being connected tout court. Path-connected spaces can be seen as unions of continuous images of I (the paths between each couple of its points): in which ways does this property make them special? I'm not a fan of this vague kind of question, but what I'm trying to develop intuition about this matter.

Well, my answer to you is that, there is nothing special about it, but our geometric/intuitive notion of path/curve is the resulting image of a deformation (by a continuos function) of the interval $[0,1]$.

$\Bbb R$ is our intuitive model for the continuum. If you drew a path in a space, $[0,1]$ would be the only appropriate model for that intuitive image

To me a striking example that shows $[0, 1]$ is special is Urysohn's lemma, where I would say that essentially what makes it special is the fact that $[0, 1]$ is the Dedekind-Macneille completion of a dense countable linear order. Another perspective is that $\Bbb R$ is exactly the ordered field in which the IVT holds.

@IzaakvanDongen Thank you, I did know these facts but didn't match them in this context. I think in particular the IVT can be enlightening in this circumstance. So has the image of such a peculiar topology any notable property (as, say, it is known that the image of a compact set is compact)? That is, what the validity of IVT in [0,1] entails on its continuous images? May it be linked to the fact that any two points of the image of a path are themselves path-connected?

@PauloEstêvão Thank for your comment. If you wish to contribute further in the light of my last comment, you're welcome.

@FShrike Thank for your comment. If you wish to contribute further in the light of my penultimate comment, you're welcome.

The IVT is essentially that $[0,1]$ is connected and continuous images of connected sets are connected. $[0,1]$ is also "1-dimensional", whatever that means, so .. is a good model for lines, walks between any two elements of $X$. Compactness of paths (by virtue of $[0,1]$) is also useful in many a proof

You can characterise $[0, 1]$ as the unique (nontrivial) total order which is separable, connected and compact in the order topology: mentioned here. "Compact" is a bit artificial there - you can replace it with "bounded", as in "has a maximum and minimum".

@FShrike So can [0,1] be characterised by some property involving its being connected and 1-dimensional? Maybe something related to the fact that in R a subet is connected iff it is convex, since a path between two point cannot but pass by the point which lie between them in the order?

@IzaakvanDongen And the "total order" has to do intuitively with being 1-dimensional? Or can this link made formal?

A further theme of reflection in my view could be the following: given a path, between every couple of points in the (image of the) path there exists a path (it's enough to restrict the previous one and precompose with a continuous parametrisation). In this sense, $I$ seems to be homeomorphic to "many" of its subspaces. Is there some theory taking into account this aspect?

Some related posts on mathoverflow: this, and this.

@AmandaWealth Well, I'm offering intuition. I don't know about a more technical formulation, but we don't need super-technical theorems to say that $[0,1]$ is, intuitively, a good notion of path.

@FShrike I can see your point and, from my perspective, I intuitively don't doubt $I$ to give a good notion of path, considering the idea of continuum and the (topological) properties that continuous maps preserve. The ground I'd like to explore is how to internalise this intuition in the theory or, vice versa, to how reinforce the intuition via a suitable formalisation. We may not need it but I use to study like this to make sense of notions.
